# Given P(X|z) why is the NLL P(X) proportional to the squared Euclidean distance between f(z) and X

Tags: statistics, log-likelihood

In the paper [Tutorial on Variational Autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf), the authors state that

> Since $P(X\mid z)$ is an isotropic Gaussian, the negative log probability of $X$ is proportional squared Euclidean distance between $f(z)$ and $X$.

According to the paper, $$P(X) = \int P(X\mid z; \theta)P(z)\,\mathrm dz,$$ and $$P(X\mid z; \theta) = \mathcal N (X\mid f(z; \theta), \sigma^2 ∗ I).$$

I don't see the connection here in proving this.

Comment: If you look at the pdf of the multivariate normal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), inside the exponential you will see the Euclidian distance between x and the conditional mean.

Comment: @fesman thank you for pointing that out! That makes sense now since $f(z;\theta)$ is our conditional mean here.